# Is $20+k^2\not\equiv4(\text{mod}~7)$ for all $k\geq0$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I've been asked to explain why during quadratic probing in a hash function it is possible that a collision resolution is never found (eg. empty spots exist in the hash table, but the quadratic probing will never resolve to that position).

I have an example where index $4$ is the last free index in the hash table, however it is impossible to insert the key $20$ because it will never be resolved to index $4$ in the hash table (impossible for the hash function to return $4$). This is because $20+k^2\text{mod}~7\neq4$ for all $k\geq0$ .

I think I have reduced it to a congruence relation correctly:

$20+k^2\not\equiv4(\text{mod}~7)$ for all $k\geq0$

I am quite sure the above statement is true, however I can't explain why it is true. Are there some (modular arithmetic) properties that  cause this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, subtract 4 from both sides, and then subtract 14, to get $2+k^2$  is not $0$ modulo $7.$ Now, just try the seven possibilities for $k.$

Comment: How come adding 2 to $k^2$ makes the statement true, but when you just use $k^2$ the statement is false? (ie. $k^2$ is 0 modulo 7 but 2 + $k^2$ is NOT 0 modulo 7) Why does the 2 have this effect?

Comment: Consider squaring the non-zero integers, and reducing modulo $7$. We get $1,4,2$ and that's all. So if you look at non-multiples of $7$, half of them are congruent to a square modulo $7$, and half are not. The same is true for any odd prime. There is useful theory that shows us how to determine, given $a$, whether $a$ is or is not a square modulo $p$. But for a tiny prime such as $7$, trying all possibilities, as in Igor Rivin's answer, is an excellent strategy. Note that we do not even have to square $4$, $5$, and $6$, since $(7-a)^2\equiv a^2\pmod{7}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\ \ mod\ 7\!:\  k^2\equiv -2\ \overset{cube}\Rightarrow\ k^6 \equiv -1,\ $ contra little Fermat.